# Converter qualquer string para UTF-8 sem conhecer o conjunto de caracteres original

Tags: php

Preciso de uma função ou classe que garanta que os dados enviados de um formulário (**de qualquer parte do mundo**) vão para o banco na codificação UTF-8.

Tentei, `$string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text), "UTF-8", $text);` mas tem problemas (se a entrada é 'nação' ele retorna 'na').

Tentei `$string = mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8");` mas também tem problemas retorna naÃ§Ã£o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem uma `library` disponível que faz esse papel sem que você tenha que ficar na dúvida entre qual função do `PHP` usar para converter caractere especial.

> Essa `library` funciona apenas no `PHP` `>=` `5.3`

Clique [aqui](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) para ir ao repositório no `GITHUB`.

Use da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;

echo Encoding::toUTF8("nação");
# retorna: nação

echo Encoding::fixUTF8("naÃ§Ã£o");
# retorna: nação
```

[EDIT]

Ou, da seguinte forma:

```
 <?php
 require_once "forceUTF8/Encoding.php";
 echo \ForceUTF8\Encoding::fixUTF8("naÃ§Ã£o");
```

Ou

```
 <?php
 require_once "forceUTF8/Encoding.php";
 $utf8 = new Encoding;
 echo $utf8::fixUTF8("naÃ§Ã£o");
```

Comment: deu 2 erros  PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in....on line 4    PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING ..... on line 4   Linha 4= use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma opção que possa vir a dar certo no seu caso.

Comment: PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in .....  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' ...    on line 8    Linha 8 >> echo \ForceUTF8\Encoding::fixUTF8("naÃ§Ã£o");

Comment: fiz assim echo Encoding::fixUTF8("naÃ§Ã£o"); e deu erro PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ..... Encoding.php on line 36   Na linha 36 do arquivo Encoding temos  namespace ForceUTF8;

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo Qual a versão do seu `PHP` ?

Comment: @ William Novak  Version 5.2.17 .... ;)

Comment: Leo,  infelizmente `namespaces` está disponível apenas em versões `>=` `5.3` do `PHP`.